# self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths from within tableView delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

So I thought I'd have a go at building my own simple app. Please go easy on me I'm new to all this! The idea is this. For iPad have a single view controller with a text box and a text field. Text box takes a title, and text field takes the body of a report. There's a button on the page to submit the report, which bundles the two texts into an object and adds it to a table view within the same view controller. I have set the view controller as a delegate with `<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` in my header file. My table view works fine for adding items in the `viewDidLoad` method. But adding items from the text inputs via a UIButton connected to `-(IBAction) addItem` falls over with: `Property 'tableView' not found on object of type 'ReportsViewController'`

```
- (IBAction)addReportItem
{
int newRowIndex = [reports count];

ReportObject *item = [[ReportObject alloc] init];
item.title = @"A new title";
item.reportText = @"A new text";
[reports addObject:item];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:0];
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

I understand that I'm trying to call a method within my object but I have other method calls to tableView which work fine. i.e.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [reports count];
}
```

I thought this was the point of delegation. I know I'm missing something, but as I say I am new to all this and have looked everywhere for an answer before posting. What do I need to do to send my `IBAction` message to `tableView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a tableView instance variable setup in your .h file of the view controller?

The reason you are able to access it in the delegate and data source methods is because they are passed in as part if the methods.

You will need to add the IBOUTLET tableView ivar and connect it to the tableView in your .xib.

Or perhaps your ivar for the tableView is named something else?

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your pointers. You hit the nail on the head I hadn't declared the ivar or set the property. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
What helped was to inherit the View Controller from `UITableViewController`, instead of `UIViewController`. Not using the protocol names in angled brackets.
The TableView is then linked to the dataSource and delegate via the storyboard (resp. InterfaceBuilder).

The parent class `UITableViewController` has an `IBOutlet tableView` defined.

MyViewController.h:

```
@interface MyViewController : UITableViewController
```